# Merging two columns in a single collection

Tags: collections, merge, blueprism

I'm having a table in Collection1 and it is having 8 columns in it. Now I want to merge Column1, Column3, Column5 and Column7. Is there any solution for those columns using blueprism

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to copy the collection with a new column, then loop through each row to create the merged values...

Something like that:

[image]

- `Add Column Field9` contains the standard object `Utility - Collection Manipulation`, with page 'Append Field (Text)', as inputs I have `[Coll1]` for the input collection, `"Field9"` for the new Field Name and `""` for the Value, as output I have `Coll2`.
- The loop is on `Coll2`
- `Merge Columns` is simply `[Coll2.Field1]&[Coll2.Field3]&[Coll2.Field5]&[Coll2.Field7]` with result being stored in `Coll2.Field9`.

`Coll1` contains 8 columns, each column named Field1 through Field8. `Coll2` is the new collection, it is empty before the merge.

You can choose to delete the columns you don't need afterwards, with the page 'Delete Field' from the same object (`Utility - Collection Manipulation`).

Comment: Thanks for Your Answer. Is there any condition that I can select only odd Columns separately and Even Columns separately? In my Input sometimes I will have 2 columns, Sometimes 4 and sometimes 8 like that. So I want to separate odd Columns and Even Columns.

Comment: @Vijetha That is quite a different question from what you asked previously, because it means the solution has to follow a specific set of rules that I can't think of right now how to implement without a code stage (handling it with VB or C#/J#). Or you could make it semi-flexible, i.e. work with up to X number of columns, (X could be 8 for example) but fail to work with something higher, by using recover/resume stages for instances where the column doesn't exist.